# How to show series-Legend label name in data labels, instead of value in Power BI clusrered or stacked column Chart

Tags: excel, charts, label, powerbi, column-chart

I am fairly new to Power BI and I have to implement a dashboard which I already have in excel. I am trying to show the transition of some products. The example shown is for demonstration. Basically the purpose of the Graph is to show how the volume transitions in the different stages per different fruits.  i.e. we move from Stage 1 "Orange Apple Mango Strawberry" to Stage 2  "Orange Apple Blueberry" to Stage 3 "coconut Peach Appricot"  and we can see their respective volumes. *excuse my Appricot spelling

In excel this can be implemented if in the Label options we tick "Series Names" and untick the "Value". See picture attached

[image: https://i.imgur.com/qXxCAXQ.png]

In excel it is very easy for the human eye and brain to grasp/process this transition.

Power BI on the other hand gives only the option to show the values (format->Data Labels") which makes it very hard to follow when someone sees the graph.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/y1u7W0H.png]

Do you know any possible way to show the names of the categories instead of their values, or generally control what to show (as in Excel)?

The current graph is Clustered column but the question could as well apply for Stacked Column chart.

The data:

```
Stage   Category    Volume
Stage 1 Orange      10
Stage 1 Apple       23
Stage 1 Mango       14
Stage 1 Strawberry  13
Stage 2 Orange      30
Stage 2 Apple       18
Stage 2 Blueberry   12
Stage 3 Coconut 18
Stage 3 Peach       18
Stage 3 Appricot    24
```

It seems this is not supported yet but I am wondering if there is a workaround or other solution.(https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/add-legend-info-to-data-labels/m-p/366072/highlight/true#M165593) and they have a community up vote (https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/33477430-add-legend-info-to-data-labels)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done now in clustered column charts. In the Value bin in the formatting, you can choose the field for the data label.

[image]

[image]